# How to use an increment an average formula by more than one row in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

Say I have a formula : `=AVERAGE(B3:B5)` and I cell below I wish to have `=AVERAGE(B6:B8)`.
How can I achieve this without having to manually type in the cell reference. If I copy and paste instead of getting `=AVERAGE(B6:B8)` I get `=AVERAGE(B4:B6)`.

I need to be able to increment 3 rows at a time. I've tried having a bit of a search but a lot of the suggestions are a bit disjointed and don't really make much sense.

Ah sorry guys, I mean't 3 rows at a time. Sneaky little edit :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's easier with `OFFSET`, e.g. assuming you want the first average in cell D2 put this formula in D2 and copy down

`=AVERAGE(OFFSET(B$3:B$5,3*(ROWS(D$2:D2)-1),0))`

Generically the B$3:B$5 obviously represents the first range you want to average, 3 is the number of rows to increment each time and D2 is the start cell - any or all of those can be changed depending on your exact needs

Comment: It's hurting my eyes just looking at it!! I know OP says increment 2 rows at a time but the example indicates 3 so I think you need *3. I personally dislike using "B" in INDIRECT because that's clearly "hardcoding" the column letter. Unless there are specific reasons why you always want to refer to B you would normally want the column to change, e.g. if you add columns, OFFSET version allows that of course

Comment: ROWS is also more robust compared with ROW - if you use the latter then inserting or deleting rows above the data, for example, will change the result - with ROWS you can insert or delete rows and won't have a problem

Comment: This was what I was after, I prematurely accepted the other as it worked initially but it ended up not doing exactly what I want. Good explanation as well!

Answer (score 0):

You can use INDIRECT() with a combination of ROW().

```
=AVERAGE(INDIRECT("B" & 3 + (ROW() - ROW(first_cell))*2 & ":B" & 5 + (ROW() - ROW(first_cell))*2))
```

Where `first_cell` is the starting cell. This allows to calculate the doubled offset.

Comment: AVERAGE() and OFFSET() are obvious. The 3 + ROW... part just starts at 3 and then adds the difference between current row (`ROW()`) and first row (`ROW(first_row)` or `ROW($B$3)`) if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Please try, in row3 and copied down to suit:

```
=AVERAGE(INDIRECT("B"&3*(1+MOD(ROW(),3))&":B"&3*(1+MOD(ROW(),3))+2))
```